# Split (explode) range in dataframe into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This question is similar to [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows) but includes a question about adding ranges.

I have a DataFrame:

```
+------+---------+----------------+
| Name | Options | Email          |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Bob  | 1,2,4-6 | bob@email.com  |
+------+---------+----------------+
| John |   NaN   | john@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Mary |   1,2   | mary@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Jane | 1,3-5   | jane@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
```

And I'd like the `Options` column to be split by the comma as well as rows added for a range.

```
+------+---------+----------------+
| Name | Options | Email          |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Bob  | 1       | bob@email.com  |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Bob  | 2       | bob@email.com  |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Bob  | 4       | bob@email.com  |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Bob  | 5       | bob@email.com  |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Bob  | 6       | bob@email.com  |
+------+---------+----------------+
| John | NaN     | john@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Mary | 1       | mary@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Mary | 2       | mary@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Jane | 1       | jane@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Jane | 3       | jane@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Jane | 4       | jane@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
| Jane | 5       | jane@email.com |
+------+---------+----------------+
```

How can I go beyond using `concat` and `split` like the reference SO article says to accomplish this? I need a way to add a range.

That article uses the following code to split comma delineated values (`1,2,3`):

```
In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
    var1  var2
0  a,b,c     1
1  d,e,f     2

In [55]: pd.concat([Series(row['var2'], row['var1'].split(','))              
                    for _, row in a.iterrows()]).reset_index()
Out[55]: 
  index  0

0     a  1
1     b  1
2     c  1
3     d  2
4     e  2
5     f  2
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

**Update 2/14** Sample data was updated to match my current case.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I made some changes. Do you mind un-marking this as a duplicate question please?

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Reopened.

Comment: This could have helped too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405208/how-to-convert-numeric-string-ranges-to-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like using `np.r_` and `slice`
I know it looks like a mess but beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

```
def parse(o):
    mm = lambda i: slice(min(i), max(i) + 1)
    return np.r_.__getitem__(tuple(
        mm(list(map(int, s.strip().split('-')))) for s in o.split(',')
    ))

r = df.Options.apply(parse)
new = np.concatenate(r.values)
lens = r.str.len()

df.loc[df.index.repeat(lens)].assign(Options=new)

   Name  Options           Email
0   Bob        1   bob@email.com
0   Bob        2   bob@email.com
0   Bob        4   bob@email.com
0   Bob        5   bob@email.com
0   Bob        6   bob@email.com
2  Mary        1  mary@email.com
2  Mary        2  mary@email.com
3  Jane        1  jane@email.com
3  Jane        3  jane@email.com
3  Jane        4  jane@email.com
3  Jane        5  jane@email.com
```

---

**Explanation**

- `np.r_` takes different slicers and indexers and returns an array of the combination.

  ```
  np.r_[1, 4:7]
  array([1, 4, 5, 6])
  ```

  or

  ```
  np.r_[slice(1, 2), slice(4, 7)]
  array([1, 4, 5, 6])
  ```

  But if I need to pass an arbitrary bunch of them, I need to pass a `tuple` to `np.r_` s `__getitem__` method.

  ```
  np.r_.__getitem__((slice(1, 2), slice(4, 7), slice(10, 14)))
  array([ 1,  4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12, 13])
  ```

  So I iterate, parse, make slices and pass to `np.r_.__getitem__`
- Use a combo of `loc`, `pd.Index.repeat`, and `pd.Series.str.len` after applying my cool parser
- Use `pd.DataFrame.assign` to overwrite existing column

---

**__NOTE__**
If you have bad characters in your `Options` column, I'd try to filter like this.

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Options']).astype(dict(Options=str)) \
       .replace(dict(Options={'[^0-9,\-]': ''}), regex=True) \
       .query('Options != ""')
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for explaining the solution. When mm() is called, I'm getting an AttributeError where "'float' object has no attribute 'split'". Any idea why that could be?

Comment: I'm guessing it could be due to null values in my column.

Comment: that is definitely why.  dropna first

Comment: so I did that (df_2 = df[df['Options'].notnull()])) and I find myself with a ValueError (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '') for r = df_2.Options... - I think that might be because you can't cast a string as a float? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: That means there are other characters in the options strings that you didn't represent in the sample data.  Try `int('^')` to reproduce the error.  If you pasted the entire error then you must have non-printing characters in there.  You can try stripping them out first.

Comment: thanks - that worked. Now on df.loc I have a "KeyError : 0". [Full Traceback](https://pastebin.com/u4k4mDWw)

I looked up key errors, but it's unclear to me how to fix that line of code.

Comment: Key error means that you are trying to access a key (in this case, an index value) that isn't there.  The way I set it up, that should be impossible (famous last words).  However, if you tried my **__NOTE__**, make sure to do that filtering prior to anything else.  Then proceed with the steps laid out in my solution.

Comment: Ahh I see, that's a helpful explanation, thanks. So, in my data, the `r` variable has no index of 0 because 0-4 were NaN and dropped. It seems to me that's why it's failing with a KeyError, according to your last explanation? **I've updated my sample data to reflect other cases that I neglected to show**

Comment: @kabaname adjusted answer accordingly

Answer (score 6):

If I understand what you need

```
def yourfunc(s):
    ranges = (x.split("-") for x in s.split(","))

    return [i for r in ranges for i in range(int(r[0]), int(r[-1]) + 1)]


df.Options=df.Options.apply(yourfunc)

df
Out[114]: 
   Name          Options           Email
0   Bob  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]   bob@email.com
1  Jane     [1, 3, 4, 5]  jane@email.com


df.set_index(['Name','Email']).Options.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2',1)
Out[116]: 
   Name           Email    0
0   Bob   bob@email.com  1.0
1   Bob   bob@email.com  2.0
2   Bob   bob@email.com  4.0
3   Bob   bob@email.com  5.0
4   Bob   bob@email.com  6.0
5  Jane  jane@email.com  1.0
6  Jane  jane@email.com  3.0
7  Jane  jane@email.com  4.0
8  Jane  jane@email.com  5.0
```

Comment: Just a question, why does Option column turn to float?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis when apply pd.Series, there is np.nan , then after stack(even np.nan has been removed as defualt) , it turn into float :-)

Answer (score 5):

Start with a custom replacement function:

```
def replace(x):
    i, j = map(int, x.groups())
    return ','.join(map(str, range(i, j + 1)))
```

Store the column names somewhere, we'll use them later:

```
c = df.columns
```

Next, replace items in `df.Options`, then split on a comma:

```
v = df.Options.str.replace('(\d+)-(\d+)', replace).str.split(',')
```

Next, reshape your data and finally load into a new dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
       df.drop('Options', 1).values.repeat(v.str.len(), axis=0)
)
df.insert(c.get_loc('Options'), len(c) - 1, np.concatenate(v))
df.columns = c
```

```
df

   Name Options           Email
0   Bob       1   bob@email.com
1   Bob       2   bob@email.com
2   Bob       4   bob@email.com
3   Bob       5   bob@email.com
4   Bob       6   bob@email.com
5  Jane       1  jane@email.com
6  Jane       3  jane@email.com
7  Jane       4  jane@email.com
8  Jane       5  jane@email.com
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for a super creative solution! I'm getting a TypeError on the df.drop line. Full error is: "Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'"

Comment: @kabaname it appears df.Options has NaNs. I'm not currently at a keyboard but when I am, I can try to provide you with a solution that handles this. Can you just drop the rows? That will simplify the solution.

Comment: ah unfortunately I don't think I can drop the rows as the empty cells still have information in the other columns in a row that I'd like to keep. Sorry, I should've indicated that in the OP. Do you think I could could create a new notnull() DF, perform the operations and add it back in?

Comment: Okay, using the **_NOTE_** from @piRSquared I was able to create the df. However, when I get to df.insert I get a Key Error : 0. Is that because all NaN rows were dropped? 

For example, if I have a DF with index [0,1,2,3] and rows 0,1 were dropped because their `Options` column were `NaN`, does that mean that when I try to do a df.insert (to put the df back to replace the original values) that it will fail since there technically is no 0?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution. While it's not pretty (minimal use of `pandas`), it is fairly efficient.

```
import itertools, pandas as pd, numpy as np; concat = itertools.chain.from_iterable

def ranger(mystr):
    return list(concat([int(i)] if '-' not in i else \
                list(range(int(i.split('-')[0]), int(i.split('-')[-1])+1)) \
                for i in mystr.split(',')))

df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', '1,2,4-6', 'bob@email.com'],
                   ['Jane', '1,3-5', 'jane@email.com']],
                  columns=['Name', 'Options', 'Email'])

df['Options'] = df['Options'].map(ranger)

lens = list(map(len, df['Options']))

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.repeat(df['Name'].values, lens),
                       'Email': np.repeat(df['Email'].values, lens),
                       'Option': np.hstack(df['Options'].values)})

#             Email  Name  Option
# 0   bob@email.com   Bob       1
# 1   bob@email.com   Bob       2
# 2   bob@email.com   Bob       4
# 3   bob@email.com   Bob       5
# 4   bob@email.com   Bob       6
# 5  jane@email.com  Jane       1
# 6  jane@email.com  Jane       3
# 7  jane@email.com  Jane       4
# 8  jane@email.com  Jane       5
```

**Benchmarking** of 4 solutions below (for interest only).

As a general rule, the `repeat` varieties outperform. In addition, solutions that create new dataframes from scratch (as opposed to `apply`) do better. Dropping down to `numpy` gives best results.

```
import itertools, pandas as pd, numpy as np; concat = itertools.chain.from_iterable

def ranger(mystr):
    return list(concat([int(i)] if '-' not in i else \
                list(range(int(i.split('-')[0]), int(i.split('-')[-1])+1)) \
                for i in mystr.split(',')))

def replace(x):
    i, j = map(int, x.groups())
    return ','.join(map(str, range(i, j + 1)))

def yourfunc(s):
    ranges = (x.split("-") for x in s.split(","))
    return [i for r in ranges for i in range(int(r[0]), int(r[-1]) + 1)]

def parse(o):
    mm = lambda i: slice(min(i), max(i) + 1)
    return np.r_.__getitem__(tuple(mm(list(map(int, s.strip().split('-')))) for s in o.split(',')))

df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', '1,2,4-6', 'bob@email.com'],
                   ['Jane', '1,3-5', 'jane@email.com']],
                  columns=['Name', 'Options', 'Email'])

df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)

def explode_jp(df):
    df['Options'] = df['Options'].map(ranger)
    lens = list(map(len, df['Options']))
    df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.repeat(df['Name'].values, lens),
                           'Email': np.repeat(df['Email'].values, lens),
                           'Option': np.hstack(df['Options'].values)})
    return df_out

def explode_cs(df):
    c = df.columns
    v = df.Options.str.replace('(\d+)-(\d+)', replace).str.split(',')
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(df.drop('Options', 1).values.repeat(v.str.len(), axis=0))
    df_out.insert(c.get_loc('Options'), len(c) - 1, np.concatenate(v))
    df_out.columns = c
    return df_out

def explode_wen(df):
    df.Options=df.Options.apply(yourfunc)
    df_out = df.set_index(['Name','Email']).Options.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2',1)
    return df_out

def explode_pir(df):
    r = df.Options.apply(parse)
    df_out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(r.str.len())].assign(Options=np.concatenate(r))
    return df_out

%timeit explode_jp(df.copy())   # 32.7 ms ± 1.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit explode_cs(df.copy())   # 90.6 ms ± 2.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit explode_wen(df.copy())  # 675 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit explode_pir(df.copy())  # 163 ms ± 1.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Your timings are unfair because your answer caters to this specific case, but will fail for any other number of columns. Generalising as I've done is not easy and certainly hurts performance. :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED, you are right. and that's why i upvoted your answer. But I did these timings for my own education, you can still take away a lot from performance of 4 very different answers.