# Issue with value error when trying to split a string range of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have a dataframe `parcels` full of addresses which I have imported from an excel spreadsheet. I have imported three columns `parcel_id`,`prop_locat`,`ZipCode`, and `HouseNum`. I have scraped together (copied) some code from this question: [Split (explode) range in dataframe into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776217/split-explode-range-in-dataframe-into-multiple-rows?noredirect=1&lq=1) but am receiving a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '` error.

My code is below with a sample data set with what I am trying to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd

def split(s):
    ranges = (x.split("-") for x in s.split("-"))
    return [i for r in ranges for i in range(int(r[0]), int(r[-1]) + 1)]

xlsx = 'drive/MyDrive/Parcels.xlsx'
parcels = pd.read_excel(xlsx,usecols=['parcel_id','prop_locat','ZipCode','HouseNum'])
parcels['HouseNum'] = parcels['HouseNum'].astype(str)
parcels['Length'] = parcels['HouseNum'].apply(len)

parcels['full_length'] = parcels['prop_locat'].apply(len)
parcels['address'] = parcels.apply(lambda x: x['prop_locat'][x['Length']:x['full_length']], 1)

parcels.HouseNum = parcels.HouseNum.apply(split)
parcels.set_index(['parcel_id','ZipCode','address',]).Options.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2',1)

print(parcels)
```

Sample data set:

```
    parcel_id       prop_locat      HouseNum   ZipCode  Length  full_length address 
0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  1234 W 500 S       1234      xxxxx       4           12   W 500 S  
1  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  123-130 W 700 S    123-130   xxxxx       7           15   W 700 S
```

The goal is to be able to take the range of values for the address 123-130 and append them to the data frame with the added address. IE 123 W 700 S, 124 W 700 S, 125 W 700 S, n, 130 W 700 S.

Any pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs from one of your `HouseNum` being a blank space    instead of what your function is expecting. With some slight changes, invalid cases can be accounted for:

Given:

```
  house_num
0      1234
1       103
2   123-130
3           # a blank space ' ' as given in your error.
```

Doing:

```
def stuff(val):
    val = [int(x) for x in val.split('-') if x.isnumeric()]
    return [x for x in range(val[0], val[-1]+1)] if val else None

df.house_num = df.house_num.apply(stuff)
df = df.explode('house_num')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  house_num
0      1234
1       103
2       123
2       124
2       125
2       126
2       127
2       128
2       129
2       130
3      None
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on your error is you're trying to convert empty strings into integers, which obviously wouldn't work. I would use the or operator to check for empty strings, and simply resolve to zero: `int(arg or "0")`