# Parse a string of mixed comma and hyphen separated digits to return a sorted list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a string like:

```
num_str = "1,2,6,10,11-15,36,4,45-48"
```

I'm looking to return a sorted list as follows:

```
num_list = [1,2,4,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,36,45,46,47,48]
```

Looking for a responsible and reusable solution as my one-liner below is painfully illegible:

```py
list(sorted(sum(((list(range(*[int(j) + k for k,j in enumerate(i.split('-'))])) if '-' in i else [int(i)]) for i in num_str.split(',')), [])))
```

There may be existing libraries that do this well and that's ok to list here too.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? And where are you stuck in your own attempt?

Comment: Although it's always a factor, surely efficiency is not a major concern here.  This is a configuration thing that happens once or rarely.  Just process `num_str.split(',')` in a loop, looking for the dashes.

Comment: Relevant, though perhaps not an exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405208/how-to-convert-numeric-string-ranges-to-a-list-in-python

Comment: not stuck... just having fun with list comprehension... almost getting there with this one but it starts to get unreadable!
`[list(range(int(i.split('-')[0]),int(i.split('-')[1]))) if '-' in i else int(i) for i in num_str.split(',')]`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'd say that question/solution is relevant for sure - aside from the sorted part which is easy to solve

Answer (score 1):

```
num_str = "1,2,6,10,11-15,36,4,45-48"
def parse(num_str):
    num = []
    for part in num_str.split(','):
        p1 = part.split('-')
        if len(p1) == 1:
            num.append(int(p1[0]))
        else:
            num.extend(list(range(int(p1[0]),int(p1[1])+1)))
    return num

print(parse(num_str))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 36, 45, 46, 47, 48]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt using a `generator`:

```
def normalize(num_str, sep=',', sep_range='-'):
    for k in num_str.split(sep):
        if sep_range not in k:
            yield int(k)
        else:
            _r1, _r2 = [int(j) for j in k.split(sep_range)]
            yield from range(_r1, _r2 + 1)


num_str = "1,2,6,10,11-15,36,4,45-48"
out = list(sorted(normalize(num_str)))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 36, 45, 46, 47, 48]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num_str = "1,2,6,10,11-15,36,4,45-48"
def function(string):
     result  = []
     for i in string.split(','):
         if i.isdigit():
             result.append(int(i))
         elif not i.isdigit() and '-' in i:
             val1, val2 = map(int, i.split('-'))
             result.extend(list(range(val1, val2+1)))
     return result
     
print(function(num_str))
```

output

```
[1, 2, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 36, 4, 45, 46, 47, 48]
```

Comment: needs an `else` in there doesn't it?

Comment: @rjmoggach just for element which is not digit and has not `-` in it,  for eg alphabet characters

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> num_str = "1,2,6,10,11-15,36,4,45-48"
>>>
>>> lst = []
>>> for k, v in groupby(num_str.split(','), lambda x: '-' in x):
...     if not k:
...         lst.extend(int(i) for i in v)
...     else:
...         for low, high in [i.split('-') for i in v]:
...             lst.extend(range(int(low), int(high) + 1))
...
>>> lst
[1, 2, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 36, 4, 45, 46, 47, 48]
>>> sorted(lst)
[1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 36, 45, 46, 47, 48]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [intspan](https://intspan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), (need to install with `pip install intspan`), this would look like this.

```
>>> from intspan import intspan
>>> num_str = "1,2,6,10,11-15,36,4,45-48"
>>> list(intspan(num_str))
[1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 36, 45, 46, 47, 48]
```

Comment: looks useful! repo moved to github looks like https://github.com/jonathaneunice/intspan ... the helper functions like `complement` are nice too... I could see this being valuable for image sequences

Comment: also usable for this case is `fileseq` https://github.com/justinfx/fileseq

Answer (score 0):

For a one liner this does get a bit unwieldly/unreadable compared to readable methods in other answers:

```
list(sorted(sum(((list(range(*[int(j) + k for k,j in enumerate(i.split('-'))])) if '-' in i else [int(i)]) for i in num_str.split(',')), [])))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 36, 45, 46, 47, 48]
```

Comment: I won't downvote it, but it's really unreadable and not debugable. I would therefore strongly discourage it.

Comment: I agree however this is actually what I'm gonna use and then I'll curse myself in a month or two when I look at it again.... unless.... I'll actually document my own code! 